# Keeping track of two different array indices in insertion sort with pointer increments vs. indexed addressing modes?

Tags: x86, masm, insertion-sort

So to teach myself loops and conditionals, I was trying to implement the Insertion Sort algorithm from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

I think I have *translated* the code to assembly well, yet it does not function. I think the reason for the problem probably is with indexing (specifically the part `A[j or j - something]`), and yet I am unable to fix it. Here is my code:

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
arr DWORD 4,5,1,7


.code
main proc
mov esi, OFFSET arr
mov eax, 1 ; eax is i, i <- 1

L2:

    mov ebx, eax ; ebx is j, j <- i

    ; while j > 0
    INNERWHILE:
    cmp ebx, 0
    jle L3  

    ; and A[j-1] > A[j]
    mov ecx, [esi + 4*ebx] ; A[j]
    sub esi, 4
    cmp [esi + 4*ebx], ecx ;A[j-1] > A[j]
    jle L3

    ; swap A[j] and A[j-1]
    mov edx, [esi + 4*ebx] ; edx = A[j-1]
    add esi, 4
    mov ecx, [esi + 4*ebx] ; ecx = A[j]

    ; Begin Swap
    mov [esi + 4*ebx], edx ; A[j-1] <- A[j]
    sub esi, 4
    mov [esi + 4*ebx], ecx  ; A[j] <-  A[j-1]
    dec ebx
    jmp INNERWHILE
L3:
inc eax
cmp eax, LENGTHOF arr
jl L2
invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

Any help is appreciated, my level is a beginner in x86 so any tips are welcome.

---

This is the point where I am confused: High level language assume array starts from 0 and moves on. However `A[j] != [esi]` as `j` may not be = 0, therefore, I am totally stuck in the index based addressing part.

Comment: `sbb esi, 4` doesn't make sense.  You don't want to subtract an extra 1 if CF was set.  You probably mean `sub`, not subtract-with-borrow?  Also, why modify the array base as well as using indexed addressing modes?

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant `SUB` sorry. This is the point where I am confused. High level language assumes array starts from 0 and moves on. However A[j] != [esi] as j may not be = 0, therefore, I am totally stuck in the index based addressing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're making things difficult for yourself trying to use `esi` as `A+i` and `ebx` as `j`.

**The easy thing it to use three different registers total for `A`, `i`, and `j`, instead of trying to optimize away `A+i` into a single register.**

So `A[i]` is `[esi + edi*4]` and `A[j]` is `[esi + ebx*4]`.

That would be the direct translation of that pseudo-code into asm.

---

There are optimizations you could do later, once you get that working, like maybe optimize `A+i` and `A+j` into registers so you can use `[reg]` addressing modes instead of `[reg+idx*4]` addressing modes.

And you can maybe not keep `A` in a register at all, and only use it as a memory source operand for `j>0`, instead doing `cmp edx, OFFSET arr`, or `cmp edx, [esp+0]` if you pretend the base address isn't a compile time constant and push it on the stack.

And then `j = i` becomes a `mov edx, esi`.

You might want to translate the pseudocode to C and see what optimizing compilers do.  (Write a sort function that takes a pointer as a function arg, so the compiler can't do constant propagation of a constant array and just emit code that stores the constant sorted result :P)  http://gcc.godbolt.org/ is handy for that, and see also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output).

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton, I already reversed all my previous forays as I really want to learn reverse engineering, hence the x86 self-teaching.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir: I updated your question to be more specific and explain exactly where you were getting stuck (and thus a better fit for Stack Overflow).  If this answer fully answers your question, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to let everyone know it's solved.

Comment: The question edit is prudent! Just checked the answer! Thanks again!